# OutputCache exclude Layout in Mvc 4

Tags: layout, outputcache

Could anyone help figure out how exactly to exclude the Layout from OutputCaching of the whole page. 
Currently I am working on an existing project. In the home/index, I am going to use Output Cache but in its index.cshtml there is a Layout="~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml".  In this _layout.cshtml, it handles member information.  My question is, how to only disable cache of this _layout.cshtml. I have done lots of research about Donut, childaction, ..., but still confused. Please help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Donut Caching and Donut Hole does similar thing, just try this example http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/ODJa210113-Donut-Caching-and-Donut-Hole-Caching-with-Asp.Net-MVC-4.html

Comment: This helped. Thanks.

Comment: the link is expired now and return 404 error, would you please update it ?